# Making operand an offset in IDA Python

Tags: idapython

I working with ARM executable.
Sometimes I have something like this `MOV` instruction:

```
MOV R0, #0xCD548A40
```

where the number `#0xCD548A40` is a valid offset but IDA doesn't recognize it as such automatically.
I tried to reanalyze the executable with enabled option "*Automatically convert data to offsets*" without of any suitable result.
I also tried to write IDAPython script to fix this, but the only possibility of conversion to offset that I found was:

```
idaapi.jumpto(address)
idaapi.process_ui_action("OpOffset", 0)
```

Which is not too much convenient to use.

### Question

> Given an instruction at specific address and one of its operands in a valid offset range is it possible to convert such numbers to offsets using IDA Python ?
>
> Which IDAPython API should I use for it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using the Ida `OpOff` function for that. That was `idc`, not `idapython`, but https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc-module.html#OpOff says there's `OpOff` in `idapython` as well. In addition, there's another function, `OpOffEx`, that lets you specify more details. I think one of those is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I happen to just run into this exact issue.

Here's what I did. Replace the `for` bits with the `if` bits to just test it on a small bit.

```
from idautils import *
from idaapi import *
from idc import *

#if True:
#    if True:
#        if True:
#            startea = 0x0F9109DC
#            endea = 0x0F9109F
for segea in Segments():
    for funcea in Functions(segea, SegEnd(segea)):
        functionName = GetFunctionName(funcea)
        for (startea, endea) in Chunks(funcea):
            for ea in Heads(startea, endea):
                if idc.GetMnem(ea) != "MOV" or idc.get_operand_type(ea, 1) != 5 or  idc.get_str_type(idc.get_operand_value(ea, 1)) != 0:
                    continue
                print "0x%08x"%(ea), ":", idc.GetOpnd(ea, 1), idc.get_operand_type(ea, 1)
                idc.op_plain_offset(ea,1,0)
```

```